# Conditional Probability by counting

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability

I have stumbled upon this question and I was wondering about how to approach the entire question just by counting.

**Two viewers are selected at random from a group of 6 local and 10 international viewers.**

Events A = **First viewer is international** 
Events B = **Second viewer is international**

We can use permutation to find the total arrangement. Therefore,

$$
\frac{16!}{(16-2)!} = 240 
$$

To find event A,

(**first international**)(second international) and (**first international**)(second local)

$$
\frac{{10 \choose 1}{6 \choose 1} + {10 \choose 9}{9 \choose 1}}{240} = \frac {150}{240} = 0.625 
$$

Similarly, to find event B

To find event B,

(first local)(**second international**) and (first international)(**second international**)

$$
\frac{{6 \choose 1}{10 \choose 1} + {10 \choose 1}{9 \choose 1}}{240} = \frac {150}{240} = 0.625 
$$

The other part of the question asks me to find P(B|A)

to find $ P(A | B) $ we must first know $ P(A \cap B) $

In some source, it is mentioned that $ P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B) = (0.625)(0.625) = 0.390625$

However, I am wondering if $ P(A \cap B) =  \frac {{10 \choose 1}{9 \choose 1}}{240} = \frac {90}{240} = 0.375  $

Since $ P(A \cap B) $ can be interpreted as **First is international** and **Second is international**

From here, I am just doubting my approach to this question, how to obtain the value of  $ P(A \cap B) $ and how to correctly solve for $ P(B | A)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  There are $\binom{16}1\binom {15}1$ ways to select a *first* and a *second* viewer from the sixteen.   That is not just selecting two viewers, but also *an arrangement* of those two.   Often this is referred to as "order matters". $$\binom{16}1\binom{15}1\quad=\quad\binom{16}2\, 2!$$

There are $\binom{10}1\left(\binom{6}1+\binom 91\right)$ ways to select a *first* viewer from the *ten* international candidates, as you had.   This equals $\binom{10}1\binom{15}1$. Thus: $$\mathsf P(A)\quad=\quad\dfrac{\dbinom{10}1\dbinom 61+\dbinom{10}1\dbinom 91}{\dbinom{16}2\,2!}\quad=\quad\dfrac{10}{16}$$

---

The probability for event $B$ is found similarly.  $\mathsf P(B)=10/16$.

And the probability for the intersection is $$\mathsf P(A\cap B)\quad=\quad\dfrac{\dbinom{10}2\,2!}{\dbinom{16}2\,2!}\quad=\quad\dfrac{10\cdot~~9}{16\cdot 15}\quad=\quad\dfrac 38$$

Comment: Wouldn't P(B) be 10/16 as well? Since to get the second viewer is international, we would have either (first is international)(second is international) and (first is local)(second is international) therefore (10 choose 1)(9 choose 1) + (6 choose 1)(10 choose 1)

Comment: Opps.... Yes.  I must have misread the event.  Now corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Your derivation by counting is fine, indeed we have

$$P(A)=P(B)=\frac{10\cdot 15}{16\cdot 15} =\frac58$$

$$P(A\cap B)=\frac{10\cdot 9}{16\cdot 15} =\frac{3}{8}$$

then by [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Kolmogorov_definition) we obtain

$$P(B | A)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}=\frac 3 5$$

Note that by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#Definition)

$$P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$$

only if the two events are independent that is $P(B|A)=P(B)$ which is not true in this case.